# Sorry, could not load the WebRTC extension for UV4L

Tags: pi-3b+, uv4l, webrtc

I have a `RPi 3B` with a `Raspberry-pi Camera Module OV5647 sensor HD video Webcam 5MP 1080p` mounted and working.

I am trying to get [UV4L streaming](https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/custom-webapp-with-face-detection/) working and have encountered a problem.  UV4L driver is installed successfully, and the web server is running fine [sic]:

[image]

But when I try to make WebRTC connection, I am presented with the following:

```
Sorry, could not load the WebRTC extension for UV4L: either is not installed, or has been disabled, or the architecture is not supported.
```

[image]

UV4L is installed and driver is successfully loaded according to `/var/log/syslog`

```
Jul 27 09:28:26 raspberrypi uv4l_raspicam[149]: Starting UV4L Raspberry CSI Camera Driver: uv4l
Jul 27 09:28:26 raspberrypi uv4l_raspicam[149]: <notice> [core] Trying to load driver 'raspicam' from built-in drivers first...
Jul 27 09:28:26 raspberrypi uv4l_raspicam[149]: <warning> [core] Driver 'raspicam' not found
Jul 27 09:28:26 raspberrypi uv4l_raspicam[149]: <notice> [core] Trying to load driver 'raspicam' from external plug-in's instead...
Jul 27 09:28:26 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[205]: failed to execute '/lib/udev/mtp-probe' 'mtp-probe /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2 1 4': No such file or directory
Jul 27 09:28:26 raspberrypi keyboard-setup[151]: Setting preliminary keymap...done.
Jul 27 09:28:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set preliminary keymap.
Jul 27 09:28:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
Jul 27 09:28:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
Jul 27 09:28:26 raspberrypi uv4l_raspicam[149]: <notice> [driver] Dual Raspicam & TC358743 Video4Linux2 Driver v1.9.59 built Nov 11 2017
Jul 27 09:28:26 raspberrypi uv4l_raspicam[149]: <notice> [driver] Detected camera ov5647
Jul 27 09:28:26 raspberrypi uv4l_raspicam[149]: <notice> [driver] Selected format: 1920x1080, encoding: mjpeg, JPEG Video Capture
Jul 27 09:28:26 raspberrypi uv4l_raspicam[149]: <notice> [driver] Framerate max. 30 fps
Jul 27 09:28:26 raspberrypi uv4l_raspicam[149]: <notice> [driver] ROI: 0, 0, 1, 1
Jul 27 09:28:26 raspberrypi uv4l_raspicam[149]: <notice> [core] Device detected!
```

Furthermore, my hardware should support:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep BCM 
Hardware   : BCM2835
```

and in `/etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf`

> server-option = --enable-webrtc=yes
>
> server-option = --enable-webrtc-datachannels=yes
>
> server-option = --webrtc-datachannel-label=uv4l
>
> server-option = --webrtc-datachannel-socket=/tmp/uv4l.socket
>
> server-option = --enable-webrtc-video=yes`

I am clearly missing something.  Any guidance is appreciated!

[Similar post but no remedy](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=124204)

Comment: Did you install the WebRTC extension? sudo apt-get install uv4l-webrtc-armv6 https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/installation/

Comment: @MarsonMontekuri Yes, but I used sudo apt-get install uv4l-webrtc per the instructions for Pi3 running Jessie.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is as follows:

1. I installed `uv4l-webrtc-armv6` instead of `uv4l-webrtc` as given in the tutorial.
2. Above step replaced `uv4l-webrtc` by `uv4l-webrtc-armv6` which I could see by using command

`apt search uv4l-webrtc`

before and after installation.

3. I tried changing option to `--enable-webrtc` to `--enable-webrtc-armv6` but that threw errors. So I again switched back to `--enable-webrtc` and it worked.